# Send Email With C# (Cpanel Hosting)

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have bought a cPanel host and the SMTP server information is:

[image: info]

This is my code:

```
string smtpAddress = "mandane.hostcream.com";
int portNumber = 465;
bool enableSSL = true;
string emailFrom = "mahabadi@exirsec.ir";
string password = Authenitication.PassWord;
string emailTo = To.Text;
string subject = Subject.Text;
string body = Body.Text;

using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
    mail.To.Add(emailTo);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
    {
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

When I run my code and click on the send button after 1 or 2 minutes this appears:

> Additional information: Failure sending mail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you double checked the email and password are right? **Also do you have any attachments?**

Comment: yes the email and password is correct ...

Comment: no i have not any attachments...but user and passwords i am sure that they are correct..

Comment: Well the error you've updated is some malformed information within the message and/or wrong user/pass

Comment: The error message is from STMP server?

Comment: again i have tested user and pass .. it was correct ! jumpel i just know this : "Additional information: Failure sending mail." appear !

Comment: @user3788648 try sowiarz answer with no HTML just a plain simple test email, the error message you're getting is most likely related to your message being malformed somewhere. if user and pass are really right.

Comment: Is SSL/TLS available/configured at all? Are certificates present where needed?

Comment: sometimees mails account (like gmail) are blocking untrusted application and u must change settings in mail to allow that.

Comment: oh thanks it wasn't a plain text ... it was HTML ... but i changed to plain text and This appears : "Operation Timed out"

Comment: how to configure them ? i don't know ! i have just SMTP Server and port and SSL ...

Comment: you can not log in to email from browser? I think the email account is blocking it...but I do not know.

Comment: yes i can login in browser !!

Comment: so log in and try to check any settings to change it...I do not know your's email account so here my help ends...try to search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed something, try this:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
NetworkCredential smtpCredentials = new NetworkCredential("email from","password");

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("email from");
MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("email to");

smtpClient.Host = "smpt host address";
smtpClient.Port = your_port;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = smtpCredentials;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Timeout = 20000;

message.From = fromAddress;
message.To.Add(toAddress);
message.IsBodyHtml = false;
message.Subject = "example";
message.Body = "example";

smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: the method is good and work for me in my apps...so I do not know  what you are doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot reach Yahoo address on port `465`, please check if this address reachable first because it appears to be a network issue.

Comment: Its not Yahoo ! its my cPanel hosting ! first i have set enable SSL to false but i changed it true and now this appears : 

Additional information: Failure sending mail.

Comment: Can you reach the server IP/address ?  you can use telnet to test the connection first.

Comment: i have ping to "mandane.hostcream.com" and its all right...but telnet i didn't test ... what command should i run ?

Comment: One easy way to test this is to telnet to mandane.hostcream.com on port 465 and see if it times out. You can use Putty or the built in telnet-client in windows, if you have it installed.

Comment: yes i have add telnet client feature in windows features ... but i forgot that how to use telnet commands...

Comment: The problem is in a network issue. To use Telnet you can Google it, very easy.

Comment: i have no enough reputation to chat ... sorry this command for telnet ! : telnet mandane.hostcream.com 465 connected